# ListGrid selection on the right

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I have a `ListGrid`, that needs to have the selection fields on the right. Is there a way?

I tried with:

```
ListGrid listgrid= new ListGrid(){
        @Override
        public ListGridRecord[] getSelectedRecords() {
            ArrayList<ListGridRecord> ret = new ArrayList<ListGridRecord>();
            for(ListGridRecord record : this.getRecords()) {
                if ("true".equals(record.getAttribute("selected"))) {
                    ret.add(record);
                }
            }
            ListGridRecord[] returnable = new ListGridRecord[0];
            returnable = ret.toArray(returnable);
            return returnable;
        }

        @Override
        protected Canvas createRecordComponent(ListGridRecord record, Integer colNum) {
            String fieldName = this.getFieldName(colNum);
            if (fieldName.equals("selected")) {
                DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
                CheckboxItem select = new CheckboxItem("selected");
                select.setWidth("8%");
                form.setFields(select);
                return form;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
```

However, as I got informed by the error log, its impossible to do such thing in the way i did this, because of reusing the `CheckBoxitem`

So, is there a clean way for right selected `ListGrid`'s?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try reordering the column in the following way:

```
listGrid.reorderField(0, lastposition);
```

Here `0` means the very first checkbox column & `lastposition` means the last index of grid columns.